# problemas con promesas

Tags: javascript, promesas

como puedo retornar lo que me esta devolviendo la funcion interna, si saco la funcion de la promesa me retorna el token, pero apenas la meto en la promesa no me retorna nada. alguna idea de como puedo hacer que me retorne el token dentro de esa promesa

```
//add deveria devolver el valor retornado pero no regresa nada
var add = new AD(config);

add.findUser(sAMAccountName, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }
               
  if (! user){
    console.log('User: ' + sAMAccountName + ' not found.');
  } 
  else{
    //esta funcion devuelve un token 
    return $this.token(user).then(data=>{
      return data;
    })
  } 
}); 

token(user){
  const payload:IJwtPayload={
        id:user.id,
        email:user.email,
        username:user.username,
        roles:'Admin'
    };

    const token = await this._jwtService.sign(payload);
    return {token};
}
```

Comment: Puede que tengas un problema con el scope. Prueba a hacer un console.log($this) y/o cambiar el function(err, user) por (err, user) =>

Comment: si le hago console.log al metodo me sale <promise>

Comment: ¿Dónde quieres usar el `token`? ¿Podrías agregar más información? El código expuesto no es suficiente para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Como dice @MauricioContreras, no podemos ayudarte más con esa información. Un console.log a que método? a $this.token?, que es $this? Nos falta código.

Answer (score -1):

ya has probado con Promise.resolve()?

```
var add = new AD(config);

add.findUser(sAMAccountName, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }
               
  if (! user){
    console.log('User: ' + sAMAccountName + ' not found.');
  } 
  else{
    //esta funcion devuelve un token 
    return $this.token(user).then(data=>{
      return Promise.resolve(data);
    })
  } 
});
```

Comment: El `return $this.token(user)` si fuese bien ya debería devolver una `Promise`